# in the absence of file extension return false?

Tags: javascript

```js
function extnExtractor(a) {
  // get file extension
  const extension = a.split('.').pop();
  return extension;
}
// passing the  filename
const result1 = extnExtractor('resume.pdf');
console.log(result1);

const result2 = extnExtractor('doc');
console.log(result2);
```

In the absence of file extension I want it to return false

Comment: You want *what* to return `false`?

Comment: like if there is no file extension I want it to return false as an output instead of returning doc as output!

Comment: `
const extension = a.split('.');
return extension.length > 1 ? extension.pop() : false
`

Comment: What if the filename contains a "." but it's not an extension, eg "my.file.pdf" got renamed to "my.file" ?

Comment: Also, what if your filename is `myfile.false` - are you checking for "===false" or just falsy?

Comment: Then check if string or file name endsWith .pdf or something

Comment: the notion of "file extension" is somewhat vague, you have to be very precise about what your function is expected to return e.g. in cases  like`doc`, `doc.`, `.htaccess`, `/some.dir/foo` etc

Comment: `console.log(result2 || "false")`